# Chrome Developer Tools: Missing "Elements" Tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem that there is no "Elements" tab in the upper panel on Developer tools. Somehow I have closed Elements on the upper panel, but still have everything else (Console, Sources).  I also tried to add it with "More tools" but there is no Elements in it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: you can use ctrl+shift+i on windows or cmd+shift+i to reach inspect tabs

Answer (score 5):

Open up DevTools, click the settings button (the gear) in the top right corner, and scroll down a ways. Near the bottom right, there will be a button that says "Restore defaults and reload". Click that and you should be good to go.